# hdfs: split ls output

Tags: command-line, text-processing, hadoop

on hdfs, the output of `ls` command looks like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 matteorr matteorr  4096 Jan 10 17:37 /data/Cluster
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr  4096 Jan 19 10:43 /data/Desktop
drwxrwxr-x  9 matteorr matteorr  4096 Jan 20 10:01 /data/Developer
drwxr-xr-x 11 matteorr matteorr  4096 Dec 20 13:55 /data/Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr 12288 Jan 20 13:44 /data/Downloads
drwx------ 11 matteorr matteorr  4096 Jan 20 14:01 /data/Dropbox
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr  4096 Oct 18 18:43 /data/Music
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr  4096 Jan 19 22:12 /data/Pictures
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr  4096 Oct 18 18:43 /data/Public
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr  4096 Oct 18 18:43 /data/Templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 matteorr matteorr  4096 Oct 18 18:43 /data/Videos
```

I would retrieve all subdirectories name within `/data` by a script shell,

How can I do that?

Comment: To clarify: this is not the output of the normal `ls` command, but the output of [some `hdfs` command](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls)?

Comment: @muru when I run hdfs dfs -ls, it gives me that out put

Comment: Then that information should be in the question. The usual advice for normal `ls` is: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no other field in the output includes a `/`, and no directory or filename contains a newline, you could do:

```
hdfs dfs -ls | grep '^d' | cut -d/ -f3
```

- The `grep` command selects lines that begin with `d`, marking directories
- the `cut` commend then picks the third field separated by `/` (the first being the info until the file path, the second the directory name `data`)

Awk alternative:

```
hdfs dfs -ls | awk -F/ '/^d/{print $3}'
```